# javascript on page load check if a span (under <tr>) with a specific class exist, if does not exist remove the entire <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, browser, directory, greasemonkey

I am trying to create my own greasemonkey script for my favorite directory listing site :)

The thing is not everything it list is beneficial to me, I inspected the website code and as it seems, each entry is under

Now, and as it seems, I am only interested with those  which have this format:

```
<tr class="project-description">
<td colspan="6">
    <div class="project-desc-inner">
        <div class="project-synopsis">
            <p class="trunk8">This is an entry</p>
        </div>
        <div class="project-verification">
            <span class="verfied-badge"> <~~~~~~~~~~ THIS SPAN
                <span class="currency-symbol">$</span>
                <span class="icon-tick"></span>
                Verified
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="project-actions">
            <a href="#">
                <button class="btn">LOL</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, the existence of `<span class="verfied-badge">` triggers it.

I also wish that the javascript process this after the page loads, because the site populates the table via javascript too.

I know I haven't done in my problem yet, but if somebody can just provide an example that can lead me, that is enough.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Next time be careful about stating correct languages especially in title, because **Java ≠ Javascript** in any way shape or form. Unless you're doing a string matching of *Java* in string *Javascript*. In that case you'll get a match. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr.project-details").each(function(){
       var self = $(this);
       if(self.find("span.verfied-badge").length==0)
           self.remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: +1, but there's an optimization for this: if you'd put matching TRs in a separate jQuery set and call a single `remove` on the set after you'd collect them all in iteration function.

Comment: @void if I',m interested only with `<tr class="project-details">` should i replace: `$("tr").each(function(){` with `$("tr.project-details").each(function(){` ? Thanks!

Comment: @void can you please tell me what specifically does `self.remove();`, it seems working but I do not think it is targetting the right `<tr>` playing with `self.remove();`  I realize that it removes all the `<tr>` even those that i want :(

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I think that's what i need, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

### Filtered selector that calls `.remove` only once

Since there're other `span` elements within `TR` that are unrelated to the problem it's not possible to write a pure CSS filter selector string (so we could either use `.has`) to sufficiently filter elements. but instead of removing each table row individually we filter them first and remove them all at once.

```
$("tr.project-description").filter(function() {
    return !$("span.verfied-badge", this).length;
}).remove();
```